# NoClassDefFoundError RAD 8 WebSphere 6.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, rad, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting NoCLassDefFoundError, I can see that the said class is on the path and if I export the ear it does contain a jar of the missing class. Could this be a class loader issue? or something else I am not aware of

Comment: Are you getting the error from trying to run the app in WebSphere inside RAD, or from an external WebSphere where you deployed the ear file you exported from RAD?

Comment: from trying to run the app in WebSphere inside RAD

Comment: Can you provide some additional details? Perhaps the stack trace, classpath, and a list of JARs in your module/EAR?

Answer (score 1):

There is both a compilation classpath and a runtime classpath. Check the Project > Properties > Deployment Assembly